# What is the meaning of E and d in this formula?

Tags: notation, random-variables, information-theory

I am trying to learn the [information bottleneck](http://vision.ucsd.edu/~kbranson/research/information_bottleneck.pdf) method. On slide 15, they give this equation. I think I understand that X is a random variable (but do not understand the meaning of the exponent, n). I understand that this equation is somehow representing the random variable X^n encoded and then decoded. But what is the meaning of E and little d in this equation. How do they contribute to big D?

[image]

Comment: $d$ is defined on slide 14. $E$ means expectation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$E$ stands for *expected value* and $d(\cdot, \cdot)$ means distortion, however you define distortion.  $X^n$ is a vector or $n$-tuple of random variables $X$. You
could write this as $(X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n)$ where the $X_i$ are random variables
with a common distribution (but need not be independent).
$f_n(X^n)$ is the result of *compressing* or encoding $X^n$: the result is typically
a vector of shorter length.  $g_n$ is the function that de-compresses or decodes
its argument. Thus, $g_n$ applied to the compressed vector $f_n(X^n)$ produces
a vector $Y^n = g_n(f_n(X^n))$. It is the machine learner's fondest hope that
the reconstructed $Y^n$ resembles $X^n$ as much as possible. In the best of all
possible worlds, the reconstructed $Y^n$ is identical to the $X^n$ that underwent
compression and then decompression. In practice, $Y^n$ is not the same
as $X^n$, and the *distortion* $d$ can be defined in various ways depending
on what one is trying to achieve. We might want for example to have
$$d(X^n, Y^n) = \sum_{i=1}^n |X_i-Y_i| \quad \text{or}\quad 
d(X^n, Y^n) = \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-Y_i)^2 \quad \text{or}\quad
d(X^n, Y^n) = \max_{i} |X_i-Y_i|.$$

FInally, putting it all together, the *expectation* operator is computing $D$,
the *average distortion* over all values of $X^n$

Comment: Excellent answer. Thank you very much